# Making a bootable USB OS X Installer from iso on Linux

Tags: usb, unix, install

I followed the procedure for using `dd` to put an OS X iso on a USB stick from Linux that is described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Flash_Installation_Media). The problem I'm having is that my Late 2006 Intel MacBook does not recognize the USB stick at all. I cannot use a Mac to install this because the Mac boots into a kernel panic(which is why I am reinstalling the OS).

command used that failed: `sudo dd bs=4M if="./macosx" of=/dev/sdb && sync`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you also need to bless that partition in order to make it bootable.

This is what I'd use on a Mac, but not sure if it still works on Linux box.

`sudo bless -folder /Volumes/TARGET/System/Library/CoreServices`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult to fix.

The problem you are having is that the native Mac boot loader relies on a bunch of things to recognise a valid Mac OS X boot device and you haven't provided them.

To fix it you will need to discover which is the EFI partition on your USB drive and then install something like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html) into that partition and let it do the required lifting.

Getting it all working is a non-trivial task. If I was you I'd find a friend with a Mac and build it on that. Much easier.